# Is it possible to exclude parts of the shrinkwrap target mesh?

Tags: rigging, shrinkwrap

I have a quick question about the shrinkwrap modifier. I have a rigged character and the character has some shrinkwrapped clothes, a shirt for example. I know it's possible with vertex groups to make some parts of the shirt less affected by the modifier, but is there any way I can do the same to the target mesh? Like is it possible to exclude the hands of the character from interacting with the shirt when I put his hands on his hips for example? (And I mean other than making the hands a separate object.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using only a shrinkwrap.  But it is possible by using a geometry nodes modifier instead of a shrinkwrap modifier:

[image]

Here, I'm using a geometry nodes modifier to acquire the nearest position of a subset of the target cube which I have marked with membership in a vertex group.  I'm then joining it to the original geo, so you can see that where it gets shrinkwrapped is not actually the nearest part of the cube, just the nearest marked subset of the cube.

An alternate way to do this is to duplicate your target mesh, delete geo on it (or use a mask modifier to do the same), surface deform it from the original to preserve future deforation, and shrinkwrap to the duplicate.  That's kinda the old way; GN is more of the new way.